# Bluring a div with CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to blur a div with CSS3? And I don't mean the javascript blur, I mean the photoshop blur.

I don't want the edges of the div to be blurred, I want to contents of the div to be blurred as well. (Am I asking too much out of browsers?)

If not possible, what would be some good workaround techniques?

Comment: for ie you can use filters : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532979(VS.85).aspx for other browsers using canvas might be the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible with an SVG filter.

The basics of it is that it's just a simple `feGaussianBlur`.

Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/aXUtU/1/

This works in Firefox 4, and should work from 3.5 up except for the matter of using the `svg` element without namespace/xmlns stuff (I think it should work in 3.6).

There are some issues with how much space it gives it to flow in; if you take that text down to one line you'll see the last in particular is getting clipped.

---

Depending on your content, combining multiple `box-shadow`s (`inset` and outset) and `text-shadow` could achieve a similar effect. The link above also contains a start on achieving a similar effect on text.

Comment: It's worth mentioning, that it works *only* in Firefox (My Chrome didn't render it, therefore I assume others won't do it too), therefore, it's not that great of a solution after all.

Comment: @Tom: I wasn't sure of browser support but I had a feeling it was still Firefox only.  Ways of using SVG are a bit touchy; e.g. background-image works with SVG in all modern browsers (I classify FF 4 as modern and 3.6 as not). Alternatively, if the actual section of the document were done in SVG, it would work. @Utkarsh: SVG filter probably won't do what you need due to browser support, but my `box-shadow` + `text-shadow` suggestion should swing it provided images aren't involved. I'll update the demo with a bit of an example of it.

Comment: It's not CSS either though I see he's looking for alternatives.

Comment: cant do a real blur without svg filters right now. and svg filters are only properly implemented in FF.

Answer (score 1):

Well... I came up with this:

```
.blur {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000000;
}
```

This will make the text blurry, for sure! Only thing is that it will make only text blurry. No images affected or anything. But I think that together with this http://plugins.jquery.com/project/blurimage you could make it more powerful!

Have fun with experiments!