# If statement overlay a div

Tags: javascript, php, css, function

I have a view with multiple projects. Some of these are running and some aren't
In the function if a deadline is passed it will output the 'days' as a zero on the view. (so this are the non-running projects) They remain visible on the view with the running projects. But ofcourse the running projects are shown with (for example) 24 days left or something.

Now what I want to do: If a project deadline has passed and the output is '0' I want to create a blurry layer over the div.

I have the following function working:

```
function get_all_open_designments($now) {

    $this->db->where('active', 1);
    $this->db->where('deleted !=', '1');
    $this->db->order_by('date_to', 'DESC');
    $designments = $this->db->get('designments')->result_array();
    foreach ($designments as &$designment_info) {
        $designment_info['image'] = self::get_image_for_designment($designment_info['designment_id']);
        $designment_info['count_joined'] = self::get_users_count_joined_by_id($designment_info['designment_id']);
        $designment_info['count_ideas'] = self::get_users_count_ideas_by_id($designment_info['designment_id']);
        $date_to = $designment_info['date_to'];
        $diff = $date_to - $now;
        $days = round($diff / 86400);
        $time_left = $days . ' days';
        if($days <= 0){
             $days = 0;


            $time_left = $days . ' days';


            }

        $designment_info['time_left'] = $time_left;

    }
    return $designments;
}
```

Is there a way to put a code there if the 'days' are '0' put a blurry layer over it.

The code beneath is the code for the view:

```
<script type="text/x-mustache" id="designment_template">
<div class="designment_view item">
<ul class="box-div bg-white shadow">
{{#image}}
<li>
<img width="302" src="{{image}}"/>
</li>
{{/image}}
<li class="p15 orange ff-b" style="font-size: 21px">
{{title}}
</li>
<li class="p15 black ff-l" style="font-size: 14px">
{{small_description}}
</li>
<li class="h45 black tc ff-l f14">
<dl class="clearfix bg-lightgrey user-dash-dl tc">
<dd class="fl br-1 lh36" style="width:74px" title="Cash reward for selected idea">
<p class="f11 ff-l lh12 pt33 reward"></p>
<p class="ff-m f12">{{reward}}</p>
</dd>
<dd class="fl br-1 lh36" style="width:74px" title="Amount of days left until the deadline">
<p class="f11 ff-l lh12 pt33 timeleft"></p>
<p class="ff-m f12">{{time_left}}</p>
</dd>
<dd class="fl br-1 lh36" style="width:74px" title="Amount of joined designers">
<p class="f11 ff-l lh12 pt33 joinedpeople"></p>
<p class="ff-m f12">{{people}}</p>
</dd>
<dd class="fl lh36" style="width:74px" title="Amount of uploaded ideas">
<p class="f11 ff-l lh12 pt33 ideascount"></p> 
<p class="ff-m f12">{{idea}}</p> 
<!-- mous over-->
</dd>
</dl>
</li>
{{#joined}}
<a class="joined" data-id="{{id}}" data-url="<?= site_url('app/dashboard/id') ?>/{{id}}">
<li class="btn-designment clearfix h45 tc orange ff-b f14 lh45" style="cursor: pointer;">
<div class="designment-arrow"></div>
{{/joined}}
{{^joined}}
<a class="joinable" data-id="{{id}}" data-url="<?= site_url('app/dashboard/id') ?>/{{id}}">
<li class="btn-designment clearfix h45 tc orange ff-b f14 lh45" style="cursor: pointer;">
<div class="designment-join-arrow"></div>
{{/joined}}
</li>
</a>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, there are ways to do it but SO is not a free code service. show us what you have tried. but before you do that, you have to try something. and before you do that you have to google. and when you google you will find zillions of threads about how to do it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluring a div with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477619/bluring-a-div-with-css)

Comment: Ofcourse I did. And ofcourse the whole code doesn't have to be provided here. But Do you know if it's possible to put what I want in the existing function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be multiple things you need to take care of.

- You have to pass `$days` as single parameter from controller to view.
- Add condition in view to check if `$days` are 0 or not, if
  yes then add a blank div within main div.
- Add appropriate styles to the `main div` and the `blank div`.

  - Give relative position to `min div` and absolute position to `blank blurry div`. Apply styles as you want.

Comment: Thanks this helps me in the right direction

Comment: Great! Happy to help you.